# Is there a way to increase the line length for an equation in Gekko after receiving "APM model error: string > 15000 characters"?

Tags: python, gekko

I'm using Gekko for an optimization problem with constraints that require summations over array variables. Because these arrays are long, I keep getting the error: `APM model error: string > 15000  characters`

The summation needs to be summed over three variables: i in range(1, years), n in range(1, i), and j in range(1,receptors). As it compiles, the number of variables included in each summation increases. I want to leave the code as a summation with the following line:

`m.Equation(emissions[:,3] == sum(sum(sum(f[n,j]*-r[j,2]*unit *(.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)) for i in range(years)) for n in range(i))for j in range(rec)))`

However, these constraints cause the error of more than 15,000 characters for a line.

I have previously solved the problem using for loops and intermediates to solve all of these variables outside of the "constraint" environment. It has given me the right answer, but takes a long time to compile the model (upwards of 4 hours for model building, and less than 3 minutes to solve it). The code looked like this:

```
for i in range(years): 
    emissions[i,0] = s[i,1]
    emissions[i,1] = s[i,3]
    emissions[i,2] = s[i,5] 
    emissions[i,3] = 0
    emissions[i,4] = 0
    emissions[i,5] = 0
    for n in range(i):
        for j in range(rec): 
            #update + binary * flux * conversion * growth 
            emissions[i,3] = m.Intermediate(emissions[i,3] + f[n,j] * - rankedcopy[j,2] * unit * (.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)))
            emissions[i,4] = m.Intermediate(emissions[i,4] + f[n,j] * - rankedcopy[j,3] * unit * (.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)))
            emissions[i,5] = m.Intermediate(emissions[i,5] + f[n,j] * - rankedcopy[j,4] * unit * (.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)))
```

I'm hoping that avoiding the for loops will increase the efficiency which enables me to expand the model, but I'm unsure of a way to increase the APM model string limit.

I am also open to other suggestions of how to embed intermediates into the summation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `m.sum()` function as a built-in GEKKO object. If you use the Python `sum` function then it creates a large summation equation that needs to be interpreted at run-time and may exceed the equation size limit. The `m.sum()` creates the summation in byte-code instead.

```py
m.Equation(emissions[:,3] == \
   m.sum(m.sum(m.sum(f[n,j]*-r[j,2]*unit *(.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)) \
   for i in range(years)) for n in range(i))for j in range(rec)))
```

Here is a simple example that shows the difference in performance.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import time
n = 5000
v = np.linspace(0,n-1,n)

# summation method 1 - Python sum
m = GEKKO()
t = time.time()
s = sum(v)
y = m.Var()
m.Equation(y==s)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value[0])
print('Elapsed time: ' + str(time.time()-t))
m.cleanup()

# summation method 2 - Intermediates
m = GEKKO()
t = time.time()
s = 0
for i in range(n):
    s = m.Intermediate(s + v[i])
y = m.Var()
m.Equation(y==s)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value[0])
print('Elapsed time: ' + str(time.time()-t))
m.cleanup()

# summation method 3 - Gekko sum
m = GEKKO()
t = time.time()
s = m.sum(v)
y = m.Var()
m.Equation(y==s)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value[0])
print('Elapsed time: ' + str(time.time()-t))
m.cleanup()
```

**Results**

```
12497500.0
Elapsed time: 0.17874956130981445
12497500.0
Elapsed time: 5.171698570251465
12497500.0
Elapsed time: 0.1246955394744873
```

The 15,000 character limit for a single equation is a hard limit. We thought about making it adjustable with `m.options.MAX_MEMORY` but then large equations can make very dense matrix factorizations for the solver. It is often better to break up the equation or use other methods to reduce the equation size.

Comment: Trying this, I receive the following error: `TypeError: x must be a python list of GEKKO parameters, variables, or expressions`. Any thoughts for how to get the data type to match the function?

Comment: Make sure the thing that you are including in the summation is a list of Gekko variables. You may need to create a new question with a minimum example to show the problem.

Comment: In the following code: 
`m.Equation(emissions[:,3] == sum(sum(sum(f[n,j]*-r[j,2]*unit *(.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)) for i in range(years)) for n in range(i))for j in range(rec)))`

f and r are both Gekko array variables, unit is a Gekko parameter and i and n are the indices in the summation. I'm unsure of how to combine these in another way to avoid this error or change the data type. Does `m.sum()` only work a single list?

Comment: Did you try: `m.Equation(emissions[:,3] == m.sum(m.sum(m.sum(f[n,j]*-r[j,2]*unit *(.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)) for i in range(years)) for n in range(i))for j in range(rec)))`? The `m.sum()` only works on 1D lists.

Comment: Yes. Essentially. I pulled out the i because I realized it shouldn't be part of the sum. It now reads `m.Equations(emissions[i,3] == unit * m.sum(m.sum(f[n,j]* -r[j,2] *(.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)) for n in range(i)) for j in range(rec)))` where i is in a for loop beforehand "for i in range(years):"

Comment: Try it with `m.Equation` instead of `m.Equations` if you put it in a nested loop. If you write a list comprehension, I think you need to add square brackets such as: `[print(i) for i in range(5)]`. With a list comprehension try something like: `m.Equations(emissions[i,3] == unit * m.sum([m.sum([f[n,j]* -r[j,2] *(.001*(i-n)**2 + 0.062*(i-n)) for n in range(i)]) for j in range(rec)]))`